# How to show messages in alertdialog randomly

Tags: android, random, hyperlink, android-alertdialog

I am using AlertDialog to show any message and links, I use this code. But I want to show a different message (link) in every action randomly. Is that possible? and if it is, can you give me sample codes for this. thanks.

```
final AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
.setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Check this link out</a>"))
.create();
 d.show();
// Make the textview clickable. Must be called after show()   
         ((TextView)d.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

what i want is: when user opens my application, my alertbox shows a link but i want to use many links and show them randomly, I will use it for like text ads. I mean when user open my app google.com will be shown and another time yahoo.com and another time a different link. Hope i am clear

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
public static void showAlertDialog(final String title, String message,
            final Context context, final boolean redirectToPreviousScreen) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertbox.setMessage(message);
        alertbox.setTitle(title);

        alertbox.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

            }
        });
        try{
            alertbox.show();    
        }catch (Exception b) {

        }

    }
```

Comment: so where should i put my links to show randomly? for example, google.com, yahoo.com

Comment: Of course put your message in setMessage() method. But i am not getting exactly what you want.

Comment: what i want is: when user opens my application, my alertbox shows a link but i want to use many links and show them randomly, I will use it  for like text ads. I mean when user open my app google.com will be shown and another time yahoo.com and another time a different link. Hope i am clear